# Animating Multiple Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following code works, but I have a problem since I want to have multiple portfolio objects like this one. If I use the current code it would raise all of the hidden divs (.slide) with text instead of one at a time based on hover. I can't use "this" since that would just make the picture animate upward. I could give everything ids and write a lot of JavaScript code that is repetitive, but I am almost positive that isn't the best way to do things.

Basically, How would you target a div with a hover effect that causes another div to do something and still be able to reuse the code?

The HTML for this section:

```
<div class="col-md-6 high">
    <img class="port" src="http://loremflickr.com/320/240" alt="test">
    <div class="slide">
        <h3>Test Portfolio</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS for this section:

```
.high {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.port {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.slide {
  background-color: rgba(74, 170, 165, 0.7);
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: -34px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The JavaScript for this section:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var portfolio = {
    // moves div with text over portfolio picture on hover
    hoverPort: function() {
      $(".port").hover(function() {
        $(".slide").stop().animate({"top" : "-110px"});
      }, function() {
        $(".slide").stop().animate({"top" : "-34"});
      });
    }, // end of hoverPort function
  } // end of portfolio object

  portfolio.hoverPort();

}); // end of document.ready
```

Comment: Consider rephrasing your question and title to remove the "best practices" part. Best practices are subject to opinion and will likely vary based on a number of assumptions and are thus not well received on Stack Overflow; in fact, there is an off-topic reason "**primarily opinion-based**" which reads *"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."*. If you narrow your question to your "basically", it will be fine.

Comment: Done. Thank you for letting me know. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can use `this`, not to animate the element itself but to refer another "closest" element based on that:

```
    $(".port").hover(function() {
        $(this).next('.slide').stop().animate({"top" : "-110px"});
    }, function() {
        $(this).next('.slide').stop().animate({"top" : "-34"});
    });
```

---

**Demo Snippet**

```js
 $(".port").hover(function() {
   $(this).next('.slide').stop().animate({
     "top": "-110px"
   });
 }, function() {
   $(this).next('.slide').stop().animate({
     "top": "-34"
   });
 });
```

```css
.col-md-6 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding:25px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.slide {
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  color: white;
  background: red;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 high">
  <img class="port" src="http://loremflickr.com/320/240" alt="test">
  <div class="slide">
    <h3>Test Portfolio</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 high">
  <img class="port" src="http://loremflickr.com/320/240" alt="test">
  <div class="slide">
    <h3>Test Portfolio</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm fairly new to coding and haven't heard of this approach yet! :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery "eq" selector.

```
    $(".port").eq(0).hover(function() {
        $(".slide").eq(0).stop().animate({"top" : "-110px"});
    });
```

Hovering over the first "port" will animate the first "slide".

Comment: Thanks, Ned. This is another great way that I hadn't seen yet!